# How to check types in C++ in Qt

Tags: c++, typechecking

I need to check the type of the input being entered by the user and if it is not of desired type, i should print an error message. My code is:

```
int ClassInput::inputInt(QString str)
{
    signed int l;
    std::cout << str.toStdString();
    std::cin>>l;

    while(!l)
    {
        eh.handleError(1);
        std::cin>>l;
        cin.clear ();
        cin.ignore (1000, '\n');
    }
    return l;
}
```

but the problem is it is not printing the error message when a float value is being entered. Also, it is going to next step and performing the calculations as if right input is entered.

Some times it is infinitely printing the error statement. please can anyone correct my code?

Comment: i think you should read input as string and then you can check it with  ... hm if( !sscanf(in_str.c_str(), "%d", &some_int_var) ) { error(); } From my pov, there is no error "std::cin>>l" will work always, with any string (im not sure). Also you can try "if ( ! (std::cin>>l) ) { error(); }"

Comment: If you want to safe-input you need to get std::string from input and then try to parse it.

Comment: The user doesn't input a type, he enters values in a specific format, you need to check if the format matches your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

I think [typeinfo](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/type_info/name/) is what you are looking for. This could be an example code for the case of a int as expected input from the user.

```
std::cin>>l;
QString input = typeid(l).name();
if(input.compare("int")) continue;
```

Comment: This is completely wrong. `l` will always be an int. And there is no guarantee that the the type int will be represented by the string "int". It is implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is not about type checking, but value checking instead. So `typeid` is not actually a good choice.

Specifically about the solution to your problem. You should add more strict value checking on your input. It is not a good idea to store the user's input in an int variable. Because if the user type a float variable, it will be implicitly converted to int. So that's why your code is not printing the error message when a float value is being entered. But it won't affect your follow-up calculation.

One another thing, if the input is not digits, but characters, 0 will be assigned to your input variable.

In order to robustly check the input value, you should change the type of input variable to `std:string` and check if the string is a legal input. Possible routine to do this:

1. check if there is non-digits.
2. check if it is a legal digit according to your program needs.

So instead of just writing a coarse `!l` check, write another separate checking function and call it here.